# How to solve ORA-01861: literal does not match format string exception

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using INSERT INTO...SELECT query to select some field values from TABLE1 and populate the values into TABLE2. 
TABLE1 has a column **ENDDATE which has type VARCHAR2(64 BYTE)** and I am trying to insert that data into another column with name ENDDATE in TABLE2, where **ENDDATE is of DATE type**. 
So, obviously while I am running the query  I am getting an exception

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException
```

Things I tried:

1. Tried to convert String type into Date using `CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.ENDDATE, 121)) AS ENDDATE_TEMP`. I am getting **missing expression error** for this.
2. Tried to use `TO_DATE ()` function, but getting Unknown command error. I am using Oracle 12c version and I believe TO_ DATE is available for 12c. But still could not get it to work.

Sample Data for TABLE1.ENDDATE: 20190229 [YYYYMMDD].

Data in TABLE2.ENDDATE should be stored as : 29-FEB-2019

I am using `TO_DATE('20190229','YYYYMMDD')` to convert the string to DATE.

Can anyone kindly help me out how can I convert the ENDDATE inside SELECT part of the query. Any best alternative for this situation!!

Also I am using the ENDDATE value for where condition at the end of the query like WHERE ENDDATE IS NOT NULL. I apologize as I could not post code snippets due to certain regulations.

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.ENDDATE, 121)` is for SQL Server, not for Oracle.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample data of the badly stored dates in `table1.enddate` and the exact SQL statement (including the `to_date()` call) you are using as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question do not post code in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sir, I editted my question to include the sample data. And inside select query in place of ENDDATE,  I am using TO_DATE('','').

Comment: Well of course `TO_DATE('20190229','YYYYMMDD')` fails - there is no February 29th in 2019

Comment: Sir, that value is just for an illustration. Pick any date in the above given format.

Comment: Well that will work for valid dates: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aa1f02ca632d827fdf540323e2326dd7 Your problem is that table1 is setup incorrectly (using `varchar` instead of `date`) and now you are in deep trouble because somehow something was able to store invalid dates in that column. You need to cleanup the data in there - or even better: fix the table and change the column to a `DATE`

Comment: Ok....Thank you for your feedback. Will try to look into that.